# create a JSON file in java with array

Tags: java, json, multidimensional-array

I use JSON-simple-1.1.1 and I want to create a JSON file like this:

```
    {
       "data": [
           [
               "1",
               "YES",
               "sp_1",
               "1",
               "xxx"
           ],
           [
               "2",
               "NO",
               "sp_2",
               "2",
               "yyyy"
           ],
           [
               "3",
               "YES",
               "sp_3",
               "2",
               "zzzz"
           ]
       ]
   }
```

I try to use `JSONObject` and `JSONArray` but I cannot resolve how to create a multi array like above

Comment: And your question is...

Comment: So, start with tutorial, probably, https://www.mkyong.com/java/json-simple-example-read-and-write-json/ and come back here when you have some code and more specific question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little helper makes life easier:

```
public static JSONArray jsonArray(Object... values) {
    JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();
    arr.addAll(Arrays.asList(values));
    return arr;
}
```

Then:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
obj.put("data", jsonArray(jsonArray("1", "YES", "sp_1", "1", "xxx"),
                          jsonArray("2", "NO" , "sp_2", "2", "yyyy"),
                          jsonArray("3", "YES", "sp_3", "2", "zzzz")));
System.out.println(obj.toJSONString());
```

*Output*

```
{"data":[["1","YES","sp_1","1","xxx"],["2","NO","sp_2","2","yyyy"],["3","YES","sp_3","2","zzzz"]]}
```

Comment: Thank Andreas, your example is perfect. I make a little change because, in my case, the inside array is rows from database, so I do not know how many rows I found. But with your help modify it was simple.

Answer (score 0):

My Questions is bad write. I don't explain that read row from database and for that I don't know how many row found. the inside array is dinamic.

With Andreas help i found this solution:

```
public static JSONArray jsonArray(Object... values) {
    JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();
    arr.addAll(Arrays.asList(values));
    return arr;        
}
```

then:

```
JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();

    // loop to database row. To simplify code example write some database row found...
    ja.add(jsonArray("1", "YES", "sp_1", "1", "xxx"));
    ja.add(jsonArray("2", "YES", "sp_1", "1", "xxx"));
    ja.add(jsonArray("3", "YES", "sp_1", "1", "xxx"));


    jo.put("data", ja );  
    System.out.print(jo);
```

Output:

```
{"data":[["1","YES","sp_1","1","xxx"],["2","YES","sp_1","1","xxx"],["3","YES","sp_1","1","xxx"]]}
```

Thank to all and sorry for my not clear question.